# how to get a single field from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays

I am using an array like below

```
var types = [{id:1, type:'Type 2'}, {id:2, type:'Type 5'}, {id:3, type:'Type 1'}, {id:4, type:'Type 2'}];
```

I want to filter values based on Type and get that into a single dimension array. I tried using filter etc. but gets the filtered 2-dimensional array.

```
$filter('filter')(types, { type: 'Type 2' })
```

Result should be just id array without type like:

```
[{id:1}, {id:4}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with [`Array#map`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjtxpKup9PUAhUiS48KHXQoC5gQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNG-88X_4BP621jc1yLUJwBxSXgcxg) after the filter the array

```js
var types = [{id:1, type:'Type 2'}, {id:2, type:'Type 5'}, {id:3, type:'Type 1'}, {id:4, type:'Type 2'}];

console.log(types.filter(a=> a.type =='Type 2' ).map(a=> ({id : a.id})))
```

Answer (score 2):

true to its naming convention [`filter()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) will not manipulate object; it selects a new subset array.

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
$filter('filter')(types, { type: 'Type 2' }).map(function(x){
    return { id : x.id };
})
```

**Working Fiddle** :http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12074/

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a combination of `filter` and `map`. Or, you can use this amazing function called `reduce` which can single-handedly `filter` as well as `map` your array. Like this:

```js
var types = [{id:1, type:'Type 2'}, {id:2, type:'Type 5'}, {id:3, type:'Type 1'}, {id:4, type:'Type 2'}];

var res = types.reduce(function(arr, obj) {
  if(obj.type === 'Type 2') {
    arr.push({
      id: obj.id
    })
  }
  return arr
}, [])


console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi **Vikas Vaidya** you can also use the following code to solve this problem:

```
function filterArrayofObjects(objKey, objValue) {
    var temp = [], count = -1;
    for (var i in types) {
        var flag = false;
        var obj = {};
        for (var j in types[i]) {
            if (j === objKey && types[i][j] === objValue) {
                flag = true;
                continue;
            }
            obj[j] = types[i][j];
        }
        if (flag) {
            count++;
            temp[count] = obj;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

var result = filterArrayofObjects("type", "Type 2");
window.console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Underscore js. _.filter and _.map can help you to achieve desired results

Comment: The op does not mention underscore

Comment: Array.map() should be used then.